# Highlighting all words including and after a specified word with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a string: "Hi there, Jack! How's it going?" or "A, B, C, D, E, F, Jack! What's up?"

Is there a way to highlight "Jack!" and all the words after "Jack!" ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by highlight?

Comment: Something like this: http://www.microsoft.com/education/images/Highlight_AutoSummarize.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jquery plugin [highlight](http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) that looks like it will do what you trying to do.